# error on inserting timestamp value in bigquery from python3.7

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-3.7

i am calling a rest api from python3.7 and I am getting api response in json format. One of the fields is a timestamp string, but in the json response i am getting that in this format.

```
create_time {
  seconds: 1604562539
  nanos: 418758000
}
```

****I need to insert this into a bigquery table in UTC format** which is a timestamp field**

so I convert this to Json string like this

createdtime=json.dumps(create_time, default=datetime_handler)

```
def datetime_handler(dt):
    if isinstance(dt, datetime):
        return dt.isoformat()
    raise TypeError("Unknown type")
```

this gives me a json string in this format **2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758+00:00**

next I need to try to insert this create_time into big-query table in a timestamp field by passing this value to the bigquery request and i get the insert error

```
 'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse', 'insertErrors': [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'createdtime', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Could not parse \'"2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758+00:00"\' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'}]}
```

so I remove the offset(00:00) and now the date becomes **2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758** and i pass this to bigquery again i get the same error.

```
'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse', 'insertErrors': [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'createdtime', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Could not parse \'"2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758"\' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'}]},
```

so finally i replace the offset with Z and the createdtime becomes **2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758Z** and i pass it to bigquery and get the same result

```
**Error: {'kind': 'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse', 'insertErrors': [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'createdtime', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Could not parse \'"2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758Z"\' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'}]}**
```

And finally based on one of the suggestions i received below i have replaced **T** also so now the date becomes **2020-11-05 07:48:59.418758**
and I still get the same error:

```
Error: {'kind': 'bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse', 'insertErrors': [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'createdtime', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'Could not parse \'"2020-11-05 07:48:59.418758"\' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]'}]},
```

I am very new to python3.7 and also not much familiar with timestamp values in python and bigquery, Can anyone please suggest a solution? Thanks

This is the code I have put all the irrelevant parts also for understanding:

```
    row={}
rows=[]
     def datetime_handler(dt):
            if isinstance(dt, datetime):
                return dt.isoformat()
            raise TypeError("Unknown type")
     createdtime=json.dumps(snapshotresponse.create_time,default=datetime_hander)
    createdtime=createdtime.replace("+00:00", "").replace('T'," ")
    row["createdTime"]= createdtime
    json_msg = {
                           "json": row
                        }
    rows.append(json_msg)
    body = {
            "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
            "skipInvalidRows": "false",
            "rows": rows
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Required format is stated as:
`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]`

You have a 'T' you need to get rid of:

`date_time_str = '2020-11-05T07:48:59.418758'.replace('T', ' ')`

---

EDIT:

I was avoiding creating a datetime object just to make it a string and then send it to be parsed into a dt object again since you already had a json value. But, if you do a simple print(date_time_str) I'd imagine you could easily match it up to the required format and see what is wrong.

If you don't see the formatting issue, I'd say go with the suggestion of [hatef Alipoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7838169/hatef-alipoor) and just stringify an actual datetime.

Comment: Hi I have updated that condition, but it still fails, please refer to my update above. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you may have also added an extra set of quotation marks. If that's not the case, can you share the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Required format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

```
from datetime import datetime

sec = 1604562539
nano = 418758000
total_sec = sec + nano / 1000000000
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(total_sec)
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
# '2020-11-05 07:48:59.418758'
```